# Trying to sort and store values in descending order. Not able to do it?

Tags: php, codeigniter, sorting

```
public function gl_popular(){
$query=$this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT new_ques_id FROM gl_mark_ques");
//echo "SELECT DISTINCT new_ques_id FROM gl_mark_ques" ."<br>";
if($query->num_rows > 0){
$question = array();
        foreach($query->result() as $row){
        $question[]=array(
        'question'=>$row->new_ques_id,
        'quest'=> $this->gl_avg_pop($row->new_ques_id),//tryin to sort according to this.
        'get_quest'=>$this->gl_get_question($row->new_ques_id),
        );
        }
        $av=array();
        //$av=asort($question[1]);
        rsort($question[1]);
        foreach ($question as $key => $val) {
        echo "$key = $val\n";
        }
        //return $question;
        //var_dump($av);
        }

}
```

the problem is `$question['quest']` gives me a floating point number. I need to store the array in such a way that highest floating point number will be first. Just not able to do it. Kindly help.

Comment: Why don't you do all the sorting using mysql?

Comment: See gl_avg_pop($row->new_ques_id) calculates an average and sends it back !!! so sorting in mysql is not possible

Comment: Why don't you calculate an average using mysql?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have a look at [array_multisort()](http://pl2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)
<del>or, to make a bit more sense, add this to the query `ORDER BY new_ques_id DESC`</del>

Comment: I wont get the max value here !!! I am trying to get an avg value in 'gl_avg_pop($row->new_ques_id)'. I need to print my array in such a way that the highest avg is on the top.

Comment: <code>foreach ($question as $key => $row) {
    $new_ques_id[$key]  = $row['quest'];
    //$edition[$key] = $row['edition'];
}

// Sort the data with volume descending, edition ascending
// Add $data as the last parameter, to sort by the common key
array_multisort($new_ques_id, SORT_DESC, $question);</code>

Comment: -1 for the strike over. Of course, it shouldn't be as silly as ORDER BY new_ques_id but apparently sorting with whatever logic should be done using SQL only